# In Race for the Galaxy on 6-cost development cards, does a player receive VPs for all of the categories they have satisfied, or just one?

Tags: race-for-the-galaxy

My family and I are confused about the wording in the instructions. Perhaps my question is best asked with an example:

I have the Alien Tech Institute card, which has three parts:

- 3 VPs for each alien tech production world
- 2 VPs for alien technology windfall worlds
- 2 VPs for other "alien" cards, including this one.

If I end the game with 1 alien production card, and 2 alien windfall cards, would I receive VPs for both categories that I satisfy (in this case 7 total), or just the windfall category, which would give me a total of 4 VPs total?

Comment: As a side note I will mention that if the 6s are read correctly, no one card will score twice for the same 6

Comment: This is very interesting, and we have not been playing it this way. Can you describe where in the instructions this is?

Comment: Every 6 where a card may come up twice is written as "2 for every X having quality Y. 1 for every **other** X"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**You would get all of them that you satisfy.**

While the rules don't actually clarify this (that I could see), the entire point of playing them is to earn extra victory points for how you've setup your tableux, like focusing on alien tech in the case you pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

You would get 7 points for your alien worlds.  The scoring is cumulative.

Comment: Hi rrenauld, I read your other posts about this game, and I appreciate you taking the time to respond! +1 upvote.

Answer (score 2):

You would get at least 9 points: 3 for your production world, 4 for your windfall worlds, 2 for Alien Tech Institute itself. (Assuming all the above are in your tableau and not still in your hand.)